# Use “insert into” only with databases that has a certain table ( SQL Server 2008 R2 )

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, cursor

I need to do a "log" with all the information of a certain table, of all databases, inside a new table that I will create (With the same structure).

But not all databases has this table.

I could make a query to find all databases that has this table I want:

```
SELECT name
FROM   sys.databases
WHERE  CASE
         WHEN state_desc = 'ONLINE' 
              THEN OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(name) + '.[dbo].[tblLogdiscador]', 'U')
       END IS NOT NULL
```

It will only list the databases with this table I want to log. But now I need to do a loop, to pass by all databases, inserting the information of the "tbllogdiscador" into the table I created. I was thinking in SP_MSFOREACHDB but I see a lot of people saying to not use it.

How can I loop trough all databases that has the table, and if it has, insert into the new log table??

The code below is not helping me:

```
exec sp_msforeachdb 'if ((select count(*) 
    from [?].sys.tables Where name in(''tbllogdiscador''))=1)
 begin 
      insert into [The new tbl log]
        select * from ?.dbo.tbllog
 end
```

I'm trying to use a cursor, but i'm having problems.

Any Ideas how to do this with WHILE?

Answer (score 0):

To do what you are thinking, you need some kind of process flow logic (A [cursor](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1599/sql-server-cursor-example/) seems to be the most fitting choice), and [dynamic sql](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html).

So the high level is we need to get all of the DB names, put them into the cursor, and then use the cursor to execute the dynamic sql statement where you test to see of the table exists, and pull the records if so.

Ok so here is an example cursor that loops through the DBs on a server looking for a particular table name, and if it exists, does something (you'll have to do the sql for @Sql2):

```
declare @DBName varchar(256) 
declare @SQL1 nvarchar(max)
declare @Sql2 nvarchar(max)

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT name 
FROM sys.databases
WHERE state_desc = 'ONLINE'

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @DBName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
Begin
set @SQL1 = 'Select Name from ' + @DBName + '.sys.objects where name = ''tblLogdiscador'' '

set @SQL2 = --Your select and insert statement selecting from @DBName + 'dbo.tbllogdiscador'

if exists(exec sp_executesql @Sql1)
  begin
    exec sp_executesql @sql2
  end

FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @DBName

end
close db_cursor
deallocate db_cursor
```